# In the W3 DOM specifications, what is the difference between String and DOMString

Tags: javascript, dom

So yeah, basically what is the difference between [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMString) and [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

W3C:

> For Java and ECMAScript, DOMString is bound to the String type because both languages also use UTF-16 as their encoding.

So, in terms of client-side stuff, I assume that there is no difference as DOMString is the equivalent of a String.

Comment: So why is there a need to make two types of them? Why isn't there >>just<< an String

Comment: I would assume to abstract the string type implementation. If `String` needed to be something else in future versions, it could be easily mapped to something else without all client scripts (or any other client code) needing to change.

Comment: Can you post a link to your source next time, please?

Answer (score 0):

> DOMString is a UTF-16 String. As JavaScript already uses such strings, DOMString is mapped directly to a String.

[Mozilla Foundation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)